# Check Macbook Pro Fan operation speed?

Tags: power-management, macos

I am having Macbook Retina(13 inches). How can I check whether laptop's fan is working or not?

Comment: Based on your comment on the answer, I'd try shutting down the computer and running Apple Hardware Test. It's possible you have a broken fan or a broken fan sensor. If AHT fails, it's time to take it in for service

Comment: Don't forget to "DONATE" to the developers, like smcFanControl... thanks to them we can cool down our Macs up to 6,000rpm... the default 1,200rpm is not enough most of the time!

Answer (score 2):

There are a few apps that are available to use as Fan Utilities - they will show you current speed, as well as allow you to enable the fans to full blast.

Here's one I have used previously:

https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/23049/smcfancontrol

--
Ed

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the software you recommended is better than others out there.  Links can change and become outdated so we'd like to have more than just a link about the software.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.

Comment: Yes, I tried. But I am getting the speed as 000rpm, none of the sound from the fan.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'm using iStat Menus:

https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/

[image] [image]

**12 Alternatives to Macs Fan Control :**

http://www.topbestalternatives.com/macs-fan-control/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried. I think the problem because of the fan. At least, once have to go to Apple care center.